# Get value from selected row/celll

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in someList)
    {
        foreach (var item1 in item)
        {
            <tr>
                <td onclick="myMethod();">@item1.name</td>
            </tr> 
        }
    }
</table>
```

And here is the method which is called when the row is selected:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function myMethod() {
    var clickedCell = $(this);
    alert(clickedCell.text());
}
</script>
```

But it's not working! How can I get the text from the row/cell which is selected/clicked on?

I also tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function myMethod() {
    alert($(this).html());
}
</script>
```

and it's giving me null althought the table is full.

Comment: You have no function named `myMethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inferring from this line that you're using jQuery:

```
var clickedCell = $(this);
```

If that's the case, let's take a step back for a moment and separate your JavaScript from your HTML.  Instead of this:

```
<td onclick="myMethod();">@item1.name</td>
```

which has in-line JavaScript (which is generally frowned upon), try something like this:

```
<td class="clickableCell">@item1.name</td>
```

Now it's just markup, which is a bit cleaner.  Next you need to attach click events to your rendered cells:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td.clickableCell').click(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Now `this` refers to the element to which jQuery is binding the click event, so it can be easily referenced in the code, as opposed to having to pass a self-reference from the click event being bound within the HTML (which is another approach, but continues down the road of mixing markup with code).